# Close multiple buffers interactively

Tags: buffers

Is there a way to view a list of open buffers and close several buffers without leaving that list?

The best I know of for closing multiple buffers is using `:ls` to get a list of buffers, memorizing the numbers of the buffers you want to close, and then using `:bdelete`/`:bd` with a prefix to close those buffers, e.g. `:3,5bd`. Sometimes I'll have several buffers open and I want to close a buffer (or at least mark a buffer to be closed) while still looking for more buffers to close. With `:ls` and `:bd`, this is very inconvenient because I have to enter `:ls` again and again between closing buffers rather than closing several buffers and then signaling that I'm done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a popular mapping that will show the `:ls` result above a prompt:

```
:nnoremap <leader>ls :ls<cr>:b<space>
```

Instead of showing `:b`, as in that mapping, we'll show `:bd` instead:

```
:nnoremap <leader>lsd :ls<cr>:bd<space>
```

(If you prefer a different mapping than `lsd`, heh, feel free to change it.)

Append whatever buffer numbers you want to delete, space separated, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you'd rather enter ranges of buffer numbers, like `:2,5bd` this variation will put the cursor at the beginning, before `bd`:

```
:nnoremap <leader>lsd :ls<cr>:bd<home>
```

But you have to pick one or the other or use two mappings. Personally I use the first mapping and hit <kbd>Home</kbd> if I want to enter a range.

**Bonus Update:** Wanted to stretch my vimscript muscles so came up with this...

```
" Displays buffer list, prompts for buffer numbers and ranges and deletes
" associated buffers. Example input: 2 5,9 12
" Hit Enter alone to exit. 
function! InteractiveBufDelete()
    let l:prompt = "Specify buffers to delete: "

    ls | let bufnums = input(l:prompt)
    while strlen(bufnums)
        echo "\n"
        let buflist = split(bufnums)
        for bufitem in buflist
            if match(bufitem, '^\d\+,\d\+$') >= 0
                exec ':' . bufitem . 'bd'
            elseif match(bufitem, '^\d\+$') >= 0
                exec ':bd ' . bufitem
            else
                echohl ErrorMsg | echo 'Not a number or range: ' . bufitem | echohl None
            endif 
        endfor
        ls | let bufnums = input(l:prompt)
    endwhile 

endfunction
```

Put in your vimrc file along with a mapping like this...

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>bd :call InteractiveBufDelete()<CR>
```

Now if you hit `\bd` in Normal mode you'll see the buffer listing and a prompt. Enter space-separated numbers or ranges, such as `2 5,8 11`, and hit Enter and all associated buffers will be deleted. The process will repeat until you hit Enter alone.

*(I'll leave it to you to add any additional validation or error checking beyond what I have.)*

Comment: Can this close multiple buffers? This doesn't work with the "3,5" style.

Comment: As it says _space separated_.

Comment: Oops, so I can give multiple buffers, which is pretty good, but can I give a range?

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate. This is a good answer so +1, but it doesn't fulfill all my hopes and dreams. I suspect this is the best there is in vim-land at the moment so I'll hold out hope for an answer with deeper enlightenment for a day or so but after that I'll accept this ;-P.

Comment: I'm *sure* this is the best there is with just a mapping, but this question is no-holds-barred. Even the controversial Python heel-hook is fair game.

Comment: I just saw the update and tried it out. Nice! To be really picky, it might be better to fully parse `bufnums` before deleting any buffers. As is, this will act funny if it hits a parse error.

Comment: Thus the last line of my answer, "I'll leave it to you...". It's usually beyond the scope of here to have full blown solutions with validation and what not...decreases the signal-to-noise ratio too much.

Comment: That being said, I noticed a couple things I want to fix/improve and I know how to reduce the overall length so I'm going to add some basic user input checking...for my own education as much as anything.

Answer (score 0):

A really cool trick I picked up somewhere is to write Ex commands in a regular buffer and then use a keymap to execute those commands:

```
" Execute current line or current selection as Vim ex commands:
nnoremap <F2> :exe getline(".")<CR>
vnoremap <F2> :<C-w>exe join(getline("'<","'>"),'<Bar>')<CR>
```

I asked [a question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/34343) very similar to this question and part of [one of the answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/34363) mentions using this command to output the buffer list into a regular buffer (i.e. the current one):

```
:put=execute('ls')
```

To me, it then seems very Vimmy to:

1. Open a new (empty) buffer.
2. Run `:put=execute('ls')` to list the buffers in the new buffer.
3. Use regular Vim commands to create Ex command(s) to delete the buffers I want to delete, e.g. by first deleting the buffer info lines for buffers I want to *keep*, then using various visual selection/block commands to delete the buffer info other than the buffer numbers, and finally combining all of the buffer numbers into one (or maybe more) `:bd ...` commands.