# Efficient way of cleaning up the buffer list

Tags: buffers

Very often, after days and days of coding, opening `vim -S session` everytime, I end up with a fair long buffer list that I want to clean.

Therefore I use `:ls` to list all buffers, and then `:bdelete` several times, with a range of buffer numbers and or explicitly specifying buffer names.

The weak points in this approach are two:

1. if I run `:bdelete` on a single buffer, the lines `N buffers deleted` and `Press ENTER or type command to continue` do not appear, and the buffer list closes, so I have to run `:ls` again, which is very annoying;
2. I have to run `:bdelete` several times, which is less a pain but still annoying.

If there's a cleaner way to list non-contiguous buffer names to `:bdelete`, that would be great, as it would solve 1 and 2; if not, then a way to prevent the closure of the output of `:ls` would be good enough, as it'd solve 2.

### Important edit

I don't want to delete any buffer which is opened on a window in any tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close multiple buffers interactively](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14829/close-multiple-buffers-interactively)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my config I wrote this:

> ~/.vim/autoload/misc.vim

```
" Wipe all deleted (unloaded & unlisted) or all unloaded buffers
function! misc#bwipeout(listed) abort
    let l:buffers = filter(getbufinfo(), {_, v -> !v.loaded && (!v.listed || a:listed)})
    if !empty(l:buffers)
        execute 'bwipeout' join(map(l:buffers, {_, v -> v.bufnr}))
    endif
endfunction
```

> ~/.vim/vimrc

```
" :Bwipeout[!]
" wipe all deleted/unloaded buffers
command! -bar -bang Bwipeout call misc#bwipeout(<bang>0)
```

Now do `:Bwipeout!` to clean the whole mess.

Note: `:bwipeout` differs from `:bdelete` in that it actually deletes the buffer, while `:bdelete` keeps name/number/local bookmarks for later re-use. You can see all "deleted" buffers by the command `:ls!`.

If you still want to make use of `:bdelete` you can adapt the code easily:

```
function s:bdelete() abort
    let l:buffers = filter(getbufinfo(), {_, v -> !v.loaded && v.listed})
    if !empty(l:buffers)
        execute 'bdelete' join(map(l:buffers, {_, v -> v.bufnr}))
    endif
endfunction
command! -bar Bdelete call s:bdelete()
```

Comment: `:bwipeout`'s doc says _Don't use this unless you know what you are doing._ Any comments on this, with respect to your solution?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis If you wonder what's a (minor) difference between `:bdelete` and `:bwipeout` you should read both `:h :bd` and `:h :bw` and compare. Personally I like `:bw` more and use it **instead of** `:bd` on those rare occasions I have to use one of them.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis You might be interested in [this q&a](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/what-bad-things-can-happen-if-i-use-bwipeout) about `:bwipeout`

Answer (score 4):

For my config I wrote this:

```
" kill-all but visible buffers
nnoremap <silent> <M-BS> :call Delete_buffers()<CR>:echo "Non-windowed buffers are deleted"<CR>

"" Delete all(saved) but visible buffers
func! Delete_buffers()
    " all visible buffers in all tabs
    let buflist = []
    for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
        call extend(buflist, tabpagebuflist(i + 1))
    endfor

    " all existing buffers
    for bnr in range(1, bufnr("$"))
        if index(buflist, bnr) == -1 && buflisted(bnr)
            exe 'bd ' . bnr
        endif
    endfor
endfunc
```

Then with `Alt+Backspace` all but buffers currently visible in split windows are deleted.

Very handy to save/update session without bunch of unneeded buffers.

PS, updated to not delete buffers in other tabs.

PPS, thx @matt, better version:

```
func! Delete_buffers()
    let l:buffers = filter(getbufinfo(), {_, v -> v.hidden})
    if !empty(l:buffers)
        execute 'bwipeout' join(map(l:buffers, {_, v -> v.bufnr}))
    endif
endfunc
```

Comment: `let l:buffers = filter(getbufinfo(), {_, v -> v.hidden})` will eventually fail for modified hidden buffers.

Comment: @Matt, yes I know. I have `set confirm` and get confirmation requests to save those buffers.